# su or sudo keeping/removing certain environment variables

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, su

I would like to be able to log in as another user and keep most, but not all of my environment.  Specifically, I would like to set `$HOME` to the correct value for the new user, but keep probably everything else.  If I use `sudo -E`, all of my environment stays the same, including `$HOME`.  If I use `sudo -E su`, it almost works, but for some reason doesn't preserve `$ZDOTDIR`, which is specifically one of the variables I want to keep.

Does anyone know a convenient solution to this, or why one of the few variables that gets wiped with `sudo -E su` is `$ZDOTDIR`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the sudoers settings vary between OSes it is hard to predict what would work for you.

`sudo -EH` the H switch tries to set $HOME to the target user's value, but this would not preserve $ZDOTDIR.

Or add the line below to the end of sudoers using visudo. This tells sudo to keep the variables listed from the current environment. In this case you would then use `sudo` without switches.

```
Defaults        env_keep += "ZDOTDIR OTHERVAR1 OTHERVAR2 [...]"
```